# Plain text chess position creator software

Tags: text-processing, games

Is there a software which can create chess positions just by reading a plain text file?

For example, to produce a PDF rich with math text, one can use TeX to compile a plain text file and get the desired output with precision.

Similarly, is there such a software (is TeX a *software*?) which does something similar with chess?

Comment: check out https://www.gnu.org/software/chess/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [Forsythe-Edwards notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) + a front-end to compile it into an image. You can use [Xboard](https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/) as a front end.

---

Check out [Xboard](https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/). Read the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/manual/xboard.html) and look up the "Load Position" command:

> #### Load Position
>
> Sets up a position from a position file. A pop-up dialog
> prompts you for the file name. The shifted Ctrl-O key is a keyboard
> equivalent. If the file contains more than one saved position, and you
> want to load the Nth one, type the number N after the file name,
> separated by a space. Position files must be in FEN (Forsythe-Edwards
> notation), or in the format that the Save Position command writes when
> oldSaveStyle is turned on.

Comment: To answer the other part of your question:

TeX is a software, yes. More generally, it's a language. It takes input conforming to a grammar, and compiles it into output according to formatting rules. FEN + XBoard can do the same thing.